# What does this mean "Wir begiessen das Morgen"

Tags: word-usage

Right on January 1st., I received this message "Alles Gute fürs neue Jahr! Wir begiessen das Morgen!" Does this mean something like let's celebrate the time to come?

Comment: You should provide more information. Did you have an appointment with the sender of the message for January, 2nd?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that "morgen" should be written in lower case here.

"Begießen" would mean drinking alcohol (like pouring liquid on it) and therefore celebrate the new year.

Otherwise, "das Morgen" would mean drinking to "tomorrow" as an abstract concept.

> "All the best for the new year! We'll **(celebrate / drink on it)** tomorrow!"

Answer (score 2):

"Das Morgen" ist eine seltene Formulierung, die ausgesprochen feierlich daherkommt, aber üblich in Poesie, Liedtexten und eben wenn man besonders feierlich wirken will.

Die Theorie anderer Kommentatoren und Antwortgeber, es könnte ein Schreibfehler sein, und "Wir begießen das morgen" - we drink on it tomorrow - könnte gemeint sein, halte ich für unwahrscheinlich.

"Das Morgen" kommt in Redewendungen vor, wie "... als gäbe es kein Morgen" und in bekannten Texten wie der Bibel, sowohl im NT "Sorget also nicht ums Morgen, denn das Morgen wird für sich selber sorgen; es ist genug, daß jeder Tag seine (eigene) Plage habe. " (Mt.) als auch im AT "..., das Morgen wird die Freiheit sein" (Buch Exodus).

Bei Bond übrigens falsch übersetzt "Der Morgen stirbt nie", denn - festhalten - im Original: "Tomorrow never dies". Filmwirtschaft. Es müsste also "Das Morgen stirbt nie" heißen.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118130/discussion-on-answer-by-user-unknown-what-does-this-mean-wir-begiessen-das-morg).

Comment: Der Bond-Abschnitt ist überflüssig, ansonsten aber eine sehr gute Antwort!

Comment: Schöne Antwort, aber ehrlich gesagt halte ich das gerade bei einer (Instant-)Message für sehr unwahrscheinlich. In einem Brief würde ich dir zustimmen..

Comment: @choXer: Wie kommst Du auf Instantmessage?

Answer (score 1):

In your quote (Morgen with a capital letter) it would mean "we drink on the future", but no native speaker would use that.
What the sender of the message means is "wir begiessen das morgen" (lower case) what would translate to "we will celebrate (by drinking alcool or "pour [alcool] on it") the new year tomorrow".

Comment: I agree with your first sentence, not with the rest. This is a situation in which people may use language that they would not use in everyday conversations.

Comment: "but no native speaker would use that" - it is not true in this apodictic form.